# saml-php error code explanation

Tags: php, saml-2.0, onelogin

I am very new to the SAML arena, and I am trying to implement this into my app as an SP only, using saml-php from OneLogIn.  As it now stands, I am able to get it working using a OneLogIn test app, however, whenever an outside source attempts to log in through it, I get the following error:

```
 Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'OneLogin_Saml2_Error' with message 'SAML Response not found, Only supported HTTP_POST Binding' in
```

followed by a stack trace through my various files.  Since I do not have much experience with all of this, could someone explain what this means?  Where do I need to start looking in order to debug it.

Please, if any additional information would be helpful, let me know, and I will provide it.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The SP Assertion Consumer Service URL expects a "SAMLResponse" POST parameter containing a SAMLResponse message.

That error means that the ACS endpoint was not able to find that parameter (maybe the Identity Provider using HTTP-Redirect binding?).

You can use [SAMLTracer](https://addons.mozilla.org/es/firefox/addon/saml-tracer/) in order to record the SAML flow and analyze what is happening. Compare the trace between the working environment with Onelogin app and the otherone.

Also visit [samltool.com](https://www.samltool.com) where you will found several info related to SAML, including the "online tools" where you will be able to manipulate SAML messages and learn how SAML works.

Comment: If the IdP has a POST binding, and yet, during an IdP-initiated log in, we as the SP do not receive any POST content, where would be the best place to look for why?

Comment: As I mentioned, install SAMLTracer in order to analyze the HTTP flow and the parameters sent by the IdP. At the SP ACS endpoint a SAMLResponse POST parameter must arrive (try to get it).

Comment: What would cause a SAMLResponse POST parameter to not arrive?  Using SAMLTracer, it shows a GET request to the ACS, but no POST.

Comment: Do you know what software is used by the IdP? If the SAMLResponse appears as a GET parameter then they are using the HTTP-Redirect binding and not the HTTP-POST

Comment: The IdP is using OneLogIn.  Is there a way they can easily change the binding they are using?  And thanks so much for the time you have spent with me on this.  I really appreciate it.

Comment: Now I'm lost since Onelogin uses HTTP-POST binding to send the SAMLResponses.

Comment: That's where my confusion comes in as well.  I have seen that they use it though, but I'm still only getting the GET request to the ACS.  Any ideas at all on how this could be happening?

Comment: If you can share the recorded SAML Trace after execute the SAML flow and and screenshot of your configurations  to my mail , I can see if I see something wrong.

Comment: Welp I wish we could know what the issue was :V